# In VHDL what is means of "if (('0' & next_a)=15) then"

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL what is means of "if (('0' & next_a)=15) then"

next_a is vecotr length 4 (next_a : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0))

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the author didn't understand what he was doing.

The author apparently realises (or found out in a debugging session) that 15 cannot be represented as a signed 4-bit value, though he is perhaps unaware that it can be represented as an unsigned 4-bit value.

And he is probably using one of those non-standard Synopsys libraries that defaults to a signed interpretation on non-numeric data like std_logic_vector.

So instead of making it clear to the compiler that he wants an unsigned comparison, he sign-extends `next_a` by prepending `'0'`to generate a 5-bit signed representation.

If he had taken a clearer view of the design in the first place, he would have used the `numeric_std` libraries and declared `next_a` as `unsigned(3 downto 0)` or even `natural range 0 to 15`. And written

```
if next_a = 15 then
```

If he was forced to use std_logic_vector for some reason, then

```
if unsigned(next_a) = 15 then
```

would make the operation equally clear.

If you read this in a book, burn the book (responsibly : avoid forest fires!). And banish constructs like this, and where you reasonably can, those non-standard libraries, from your own code.

Comment: Thank you!  I knows what is proper method from your answer!